# Google Chrome browser does not show background images not unless I try to touch that element's CSS via inspecting tool (inspect element)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image

Google Chrome browser does not show background images not unless I try to touch that element's CSS via inspecting tool (inspect element).

I have an anchor tag set with the following properties:

```
display: block;
float: left;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
text-indent: -9999px;
background: url("img/icon-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
```

There's nothing wrong with the code, right? I don't know why when I load my page, they are all blank. But when I inspect element and click on the background image url link, it is not broken. And when I try renaming the url of the image still using the inspect element, and retype the real url, it will then appear in the page.

I also tried checking opening my site on other computer's google chrome but still it doesnt open. I'm pretty sure from the beginning when I started builidng this site, the images were showing. I dont know why all of this happened suddenly.

I also checked my console log, there is no error or anything...

Can someone help?

Comment: Depending on your folder structure try changing the image link to: url("./img/icon-sprite.png") Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: Yes, a live link would be best. Or can you reproduce the issue in a jsFiddle or CodePen?

Comment: which version of chrome would help a little more!

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra closing bracket on your code ")" . Remove that

```
background: url("img/icon-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 0 transparent);
```

to

```
background: url("img/icon-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
```

Comment: oh sorry.. i just mistyped that here in this post. not actually in my real file. sorryyyy